# "Can not resolve symbol" for many symbols in Android build.gradle leading to build failure

Tags: android, gradle

I have InteliJ Idea 2018.1, using it also for Android development. I have been using this configuration for many months, without any problems...
Unfortunatley I am still new to Android/InteliJ and can not resolve the problem, which I am facing at this moment:

When I try to create just basic Android project, my build.gradle is showing following information:

Symbols applicationId, versionCode, versionName, testInstrumentationRunner, exclude symbols "Can not be resolved"

Finally build fails:

> Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
>        Required by:
>            project :app > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

Naturally when I erase "testCompile" statemens, the build succeeds. But I am afraid, that my default configuration of Android SDK in InteliJ Idea is wrong and I do not know how to fix this. I have suspicion, that this problem has started after modifying default project structure in InteliJ (project language level), but reverting this change does not help...

My build.gradle is following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.tcc.andtesttest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Top level build.gradle file is following:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to identify what is wrong with my InteliJ/Andoid SDK configuration?

Comment: Why are you excluding `support-annotations` from espresso? Are you sure you are fetching it from another library somewhere?

Comment: This build.gradle is automatically generated once a new project is opened. The only modification, which I have done is :     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' But exclude symbol "Can not be resolved", which I think is the root of the problem...

Comment: Then your Android Plugin is out of date. The Android platform is changing rapidly anyways and thus I recommend you to use Android Studio as it is updated much faster than the IntelliJ plugin